# Stop the jcarousel Lite animation on mouseover?

Tags: jquery, jcarousel, jcarousellite

I am trying to stop the animation of my jcarouselled item when the user is hovering over a particular item. I am scrolling non-image content and I want to give user an opportunity to read the scrolled text.

How to do it? It is not even mentioned on the documentation.

Comment: This issue has been fixed. Please take a look: http://code.google.com/p/jcarausel-lite-pause-on-hover-fixed/

Comment: See also answers at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8013595/autoslide-jquery-jcarousel-lite-not-working

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this modified jCarosel Lite script

http://www.webdesignbooth.com/demo/news-ticker/jcarousellite_1.0.1c4.js

Comment: I needed to make a few mods to this to make it work properly with the `btnGo` directive. If anyone needs this, let me know and I will share

Comment: url not found !

Answer (score 0):

Your Modified jCarosel Lite script  helped me to solve my problem also. Thanks Starx. But I was not finding the way how to use the Command as I am learner yet.

later I got that, I used on two slider on a page. They are:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $(".scrollMore .carousel").jCarouselLite({
        btnNext: ".scrollMore .next",
        btnPrev: ".scrollMore .prev",
        scroll: 1,
        visible: 4,
        mouseWheel: true,
        auto: 800,
        speed: 1500,
        hoverPause: true,
    });

    $(".scrollMore .carouselClient").jCarouselLite({
        btnNext: ".scrollMore .next",
        btnPrev: ".scrollMore .prev",
        scroll: 1,
        visible: 2,
        mouseWheel: true,
        auto: 800,
        speed: 3000,
        hoverPause: true,
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Thought it will help someone who using http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/examples/

```
$('.jcarousel').hover(function() {
    $(this).jcarouselAutoscroll('stop');
}, function() {
    $(this).jcarouselAutoscroll('start');
});
```