# autoslide jQuery jCarousel Lite not working

Tags: jquery, hover, mouseover, jcarousellite

I have a `div` and it contains elements like this:

```
 <div class='anyClass' style='float:left'>
 <ul class="slider_ctre" id="mycarousel">
    <li class="outer_prdcts"><asp:HyperLink ID="hyp0" runat="server"   NavigateUrl="http://192.168.20.120/tabid/62/Gifts+++Jewelery/HOuse+Of+Jamal+Attar/Jamal+Collection/0/SKU/1016-1637-2699-0/Default.aspx"><img class="prdct_img_blue" src="/Portals/_default/images/image_1.jpg" alt='' width='100' height='100' /></asp:HyperLink></li>
    <li class="outer_prdcts"><asp:HyperLink ID="hyp1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="http://192.168.20.120/tabid/62/Gifts+++Jewelery/HOuse+Of+Jamal+Attar/Jamal+Collection/0/SKU/1016-1637-2699-0/Default.aspx"><img class="prdct_img_blue" src='/Portals/_default/images/image_2.jpg' alt='' width='100' height='100' /></asp:HyperLink></li>
    <li class="outer_prdcts"><img class="prdct_img_blue" src='/Portals/_default/images/image_3.jpg' alt='' width='100' height='100' /></li>
    <li class="outer_prdcts"><img class="prdct_img_blue" src='/Portals/_default/images/image_4.jpg' alt='' width='100' height='100' /></li>
    <li class="outer_prdcts"><img class="prdct_img_blue" src='/Portals/_default/images/image_5.jpg' alt='' width='100' height='100' /></li>
    <li class="outer_prdcts"><img class="prdct_img_blue" src='/Portals/_default/images/image_6.jpg' alt='' width='100' height='100' /></li>
 </ul>

 </div>
```

I am using jQuery jCarousel Lite  to slide these images.  My requirement is how can I stop its scrolling on mouseover?

jQuery is:

```
   <script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>
   $(function() {
    $('.anyClass').jCarouselLite({
    btnNext: '.next',
    btnPrev: '.prev',
    auto: 200
    });

    });
   </script>
```

Comment: Go to [this page](http://www.gmarwaha.com/blog/2007/08/09/jcarousel-lite-a-jquery-plugin/?cp=14), search for "pause on hover" and you'll find the code alterations you need to make to the jCarouselLite JS file to make this happen. There are only a few lines so it should be an easy job

Comment: ok i will...thanks for your comment Sparky and Clive

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stop the jcarousel Lite animation on mouseover?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352107/stop-the-jcarousel-lite-animation-on-mouseover)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, [jCarousel Lite](http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/#doc) does not offer the pause option.

There is a [discussion here about making a modification](http://old.nabble.com/JCarouselLite---pause-scrolling-td25198876s27240.html) to jCarousel Lite to add a pause option.

[According to comments on the jCarousel Lite website](http://www.gmarwaha.com/blog/2007/08/09/jcarousel-lite-a-jquery-plugin/?cp=14), the modifications to the un-minified `jcarousellite.js` file are as follows:

Add this to the list of options (under the `o = $.extend({` line).

```
pause: false
```

Find this section:

```
if(o.auto)
        setInterval(function() {
            go(curr+o.scroll);
        }, o.auto+o.speed);
```

And replace it with this:

```
if(o.auto)
    aktiv = setInterval(function() {
        go(curr+o.scroll);
    }, o.auto+o.speed);

if(o.pause)
    div.mouseover(function() {
        clearInterval(aktiv);
    });
    div.mouseout(function() {
        aktiv = setInterval(function() {
            go(curr+o.scroll);
        }, o.auto+o.speed);
    });
```

Within your `jCarouselLite()` parameters, include it like this...

```
pause: true
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a page, 
and if two or more runs jCarouselLite,
variables **o** need to explicitly add the extension object in aktiv.

```
o = $.extend({
    aktiv: null,
    pause: false
```

and aktiv changes o.aktiv

before code: aktiv
after code: o.aktiv

```
if(o.auto)
    o.aktiv = setInterval(function() {
        go(curr+o.scroll);
    }, o.auto+o.speed);

if(o.pause) {
    div.mouseover(function() {
        clearInterval(o.aktiv);
    });
    div.mouseout(function() {
        o.aktiv = setInterval(function() {
            go(curr+o.scroll);
        }, o.auto+o.speed);
    });
}
```

finished :D