# Stop jQuery animation on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have this code in my theme:

```
<script type="text/javascript">             
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){                                
        var testimonials = $(".single-testimonial_<?php echo $ID; ?   >").find('ul').children().length;                                  
        $(".single-testimonial_<?php echo $ID; ?>").jCarouselLite({
          btnNext: ".gon_<?php echo $ID; ?>",
          btnPrev: ".pon_<?php echo $ID; ?>",
          auto:3100,                
          visible: testimonials
        });
    });
})(jQuery);

</script>
```

PHP FILE:
http://codetidy.com/8399/

What should I add, to make it stop the animation on hover. I'm not into jQuery, so please, write the exact code if you know it.

Thanks!

Comment: Sry, didnt know that it was needed?

Comment: since you are using a plugin , all the animations are actually handled within the plugin. if you want to modify that , you would need to consult the documentation of the plugin or go through the code yourself and figure it out

Comment: thx, I was thinking about using something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14616818/how-to-use-stop-properly-in-jquery-animation-with-hover-event

Comment: I added the php file.

Comment: I recommend adding "JCarousel" to the question title...

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using custom jCarouselLite.

[Stop the jcarousel Lite animation on mouseover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352107/stop-the-jcarousel-lite-animation-on-mouseover).

I found it after 3h of research.